# How to use a submit button(login button) for starting new activity in case of no USER PASSWORD DATABASE?

Tags: java, android

I am using an asynctask to get text whatever the users type. How to start a new activity after users type and click login(submit button).

My code is

```
public class MainActivity2 extends MainActivity {

  EditText bQ, bR;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        bQ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        bR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    public void insertIntoDatabase() {
        final String username = bQ.getText().toString();
        final String password = bR.getText().toString();

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramUsername = params[0];
                String paramPassword = params[1];

                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://passwds.esy.es/upload.php");
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    //OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    String userPass = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramUsername, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramPassword, "UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(userPass);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.v("Result:", result);
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(username, password);
    }
    public void submit(View view) {
        insertIntoDatabase();
    }


}
```

I dont have any database. I am just want to get text but at the same time if users select login i want to start a new activity. I dont know how to add multiple function to the login button in this context.

Comment: you can do other operations in onPostExecute()

Comment: are you transmitting credentials over HTTP? **Big NOGO**!

Comment: No I just have a simple text view , using it like trnsmission of msg  like thing

Comment: Please help me how to add onPostExecute. Actually  I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to navigate to another activity on button click (Login button click) , Then create a button in your xml (activity_main2) and on button click , fetch the details from edittext and do Db operation or send the details to server for authorization and fire an intent passing your current activity and to be navigated activity.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity{
EditText bQ, bR;
Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    bQ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    bR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        insertIntoDatabase();
       // Navigate to new activity based on the response from the server . 
        intent i=new intent (MainActivity2 .this , "your new activity name where 
        you want to navigate".class) ;
        startActivity(i);

        }
    });

public void insertIntoDatabase() {
    final String username = bQ.getText().toString();
    final String password = bR.getText().toString();

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramPassword = params[1];

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://passwds.esy.es/upload.php");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                //OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                String userPass = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramUsername, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramPassword, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(userPass);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.v("Result:", result);
        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(username, password);
}
// public void submit(View view) {
//     insertIntoDatabase();
// }


}
```

Happy Coding :)